# RegExp URL validation

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var re = /^(https?:\/\/)?([0-9a-z\.-]+)[^-]\.([a-z]{2,9}\.?)([\/#].\S*)*$/i;


re.test("http://zcontest.ru/dir%201/dir_2/program.ext?var1=x&var2=my%20value");
re.test("http://zcontest.ru/dir%201/dir_2/program.ext&var1=x&var2=my%20value");
```

Hi guys. What i must add or change, so that parametres in URL cant start with &(ampersand), like in second example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to modify your initial regex as little as possible, since it was unclear exactly what your goal was. Here is the regex as you asked:

`^(https?:\/\/)?([0-9a-z\.-]+)[^-]\.([a-z]{2,9}\.?)([\/#].[^?\s]*)*\?([^\t \n]*)*$`

Also if you are not having a multiline string being checked, then the `\n` is unnecessary. Additionally note that it will **not** match strings which do not contain a `?`, such as:

`http://zcontest.ru/dir%201/dir_2/program.ext`